# how to validate country name in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables, profiles and regions.
in regions table I have list of all countries name. and in profiles table I have profile for my users and one of the field in that table in 'country'

Previously I was giving users an input box to enter country name but recently I noticed that few people are entering wrong information there. One guy entered 'jupiter' as his country name.

now what I wanna do is in my Profile model is something like this:

```
'country must exist' => array(
    'rule' => 'countryValidation',
    'message' => 'There is no such country' 
)

public function countryValidation($check) {
    $country = strtolower($this->data['Profile']['country']);
    $countries = array();
    $regions = $this-Region->find('all');
    foreach($regions as $region){
        array_push($countries, strtolower($region['Region']['country']));
    }               

    return in_array($country,$countries);   
}
```

and I am sure that the problem here is with

```
$regions = $this-Region->find('all');
```

What's the correct way to validate country?

BTW, I can't give a drop down list of country because it mess up with my layout/website design.

Comment: provide a auto complete, and auto complete must match name of country from country list database

Comment: yes, how to implement that "must match name of country" part?

Comment: you must have a database with country name for that , you can then simply match it . If you have any difficult matching name of country you can tell me

Comment: You are not getting my point. Autocomplete can give them suggestions about the possible country names but users can still type in name such as "Jupiter" in country field and I won't be able to validate that's "jupiter" is not a valid country name.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between the Profile and Region models? If not, you need to follow @Abhishek answer. Also, you have a typo in your code. It should be: `$regions = $this->Region->find('all');` (the **>** before Region).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is a  bad idea, as you can't guarantee that end users will spell the names of the countries correctly etc.......

At any rate, create a custom function in your model

```
public function myFunction($countryName){
      return in_array($countryName,$countriesList);
}
```

where `$countriesList` is an array of country names.

In the model validation you can do the following

```
 public $validate = array(
        'country' => array(
            'rule' => 'myFunction',
            'message' => 'Insert custom message here'
        )
    );
```

EDIT:

Then I would create a custom find function in the Region model, and call it from the current model to retrieve an array of results for validation. Something like:

```
$countriesList = $this->Region->customFunction();
```

or `$countriesList = $this->Region->find('list);`

Comment: indeed that's what i wanna do. but the point is how to populate $countriesList

I mean how to fetch data from a different model
I'm in Profile model and I want to fetch data from Region model. `$regions = $this-Region->find('all');` ain't working.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this to use a model in another model

```
    App::uses('Model', 'Region');
    $Region = new Region();
    $regions = $Region->find('all');
```